# Android SDKManager can't update

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I click `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe`

It will get information below:

> Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com refused

but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

The failed to fetch URL problem still exists.

Comment: Can you ping "dl-ssl.goolge.com",check you website can response you host. If can't , you can update with proxy(like vpn) or some mirror sites!

Comment: "ping dl-ssl.goolge.com" result : it can't be found. I set a proxy ,but it doesn't work. proxy:mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn  port:80

Comment: proxy problem. try not to use proxy or restart modem

Comment: How to restart modem ?

Comment: Your internet modem. You can access it, don't you?

Comment: Even though the above link is for Eclipse, the SDK Manager is the same.

Comment: I try eclipse ,it will open the same SDK Manger, the can't fetech problem is the same

Comment: I restart my Network Card ,it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Tools->Options...
set a well proxy that can reach server. Some mirrors can use in China,maybe can use! good luck!
https://github.com/inferjay/AndroidDevTools
  [image]

Comment: "https://github.com/inferjay/AndroidDevTools"  I can't download anything normally in this website.

Comment: set htttp proxy server value : mirrors.opencas.cn and set http proxy port value ：80

Comment: I try this, it still cannot get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you are Chinese,so you know,you should learn how to out of the GW,you can use vpn,such as xxnet,lantern,the most easy way ,I think ,to this url http://www.androiddevtools.cn/ ,and than you can update AndroidSdk.